# Applescript - How to paste Notes compatible RTF

Tags: macos, applescript, copy-paste, rtf

I have an AppleScript app that would like to create a note (in Apple Notes) that uses the checklist feature. Apple Notes apparently uses a special version of Rich Text Format (RTF) (com.apple.notes.richtext) to implement these checklists. Below is my very simple test script:

```
set notesRichTextFromClipboard to get the clipboard
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    tell account "iCloud"
        make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:"Test Note", body:notesRichTextFromClipboard}
    end tell
end tell
```

Before I run this script, I copy a test note that has a checklist in it:

[image]

After the script runs, I get a note that looks like this:

[image]

Clearly, the Apple version of RTF is not getting copied from the clipboard.  How do I get the Apple version of RTF (com.apple.notes.richtext) from the clipboard?

Comment: The RTF is copied to the clipboard (e.g. paste into Notes, TextEdit, etc), but note that `body` is the HTML content.

Comment: Thanks @red_menace for pointing that out!! It gave me what I needed to come up with a different solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [red_menace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10853463/red-menace) for pointing that out, I had missed that. Given that, I changed the way I preformed the "paste" operation.  Here is the solution that I came up with:

```
set notesRichTextFromClipboard to get the clipboard
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    tell account "iCloud"
        show (make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:" "})
        tell application "System Events"
            tell application process "Notes"
                keystroke "v" using {command down}
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

There may be better ways to do this.